# Android mobile indicating app contains a virus in a newly build app

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing a new application with the latest version of Android Studio, Gradle and Gradle Plugin. For the moment, the app only has a toolbar and a single activity.

Whenever I try to debug it on my mobile, it shows me that the app contains a virus and uninstall it or ignore it.

I've not installed any 3rd party libraries/dependencies yet.

Comment: You can install it. With out any problem because it is only warning to prevent you from virus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some mobile phones have built in feature to scan the new apps that is getting installed in your phone. Since the newly developed apps is not recognised and have permission loopholes & bugs. the app that scans your debug app shows you a warning. **Its Completely safe to ignore the warning** and debug your application **unless its developed by you.**